# Storing billions of IPv6 with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, ipv6

I've faced the problem to track usage of IPv6 in our network. Currently Django have GenericIPAddressField that handles both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and stores them as CHAR(39) in MySQL. For some time it was enough for our needs to process IPv4 and IPv6 the same way.

BUT, now we have clients with hundreds of thousands of allocated IPv6 and with potential billions of IPv6 there must be completely different approach to store.

What is the proven way to deal with billions of objects (not only IPv6)?

**UPD**: According to comments - "do not store", "do not track usage", "why you need stats?". Is it OK to tell customers - usage stats is disabled for IPv6, so you can't see how many IPs is used in your network, who is using it, how many IPs available in your allocation, why newly allocated IP is used by someone and when it happened? Is it ok for IPv6 networks in common? Is it secure?
Anyone can assign any IPv6, do crazy stuff, remove IPv6 from interface and you even have no idea who it was.

With our current CMDB software we can track all IPv4 activity in our network. Who, when, how long is used specific IPv4 address. This helps us to block malicious activity. If we can't do the same with IPv6, then how to live further? :)

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the IP addresses apart from storing them.  (Indeed, if you only want to store them, then arguably you don't **need** to store them.!)

Comment: Often de last 64 bits of an IPv6 address are randomly generated and they change over time. Maybe you can save some space by only saving the /64 subnet instead of the whole address?

Comment: How to track allocations? How to track usage stats? I can use NDP to find used/not used. But IP can be allocated to user and not used. Yes, currently we allocate by /64 network and do not track individual IPs. But we miss usage stats here.

Comment: What type of usage statistics are you wanting? Also, you must understand that it is billions of billions. There are `18,446,744,073,709,551,616` possible addresses on a standard IPv6 `/64` network.

Comment: Added UPD section with my thoughts.

Comment: I really don't understand the tracking of malicious activity in this way. This seems a pretty poor inefficient way to do it, and there are other tools for that. Also, your DHCP server could give you a lot of what you are trying to track.

Comment: How DHCP deals with self assigned IPs? 
> and there are other tools for that
what kind of tools?

Comment: Most people use DHCP to assign IP addresses. There are a wide variety of tools to detect malicious traffic. From anti-virus to IPS. You should be running a combination of these.